# Passing values from returned JSON to controlling statement outside call loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a piece of software im using to access an API and the API returns a total field in the JSON that indicates the amount of objects that are returned from a search. (lets call is `objectSize`)

I am then running a loop to call for paginated JSON that needs to continue up until this objectSize is reached.

I tried

```
if (response.tracks.total)
{
  getTheTotal(response.tracks.total)
  analyse(response,priorityValue,thisOffset)
}
```

on Ajax success

then outside in the loop im using to call the Ajax functions ive done

```
function getTheTotal(inTotal){
  globalTotal=inTotal
}
```

Ive globally declared `globalTotal` already.
I have had times where it seems the value has reached the `globalTotal` OUTSIDE the ajax call but generally it stays set at the value originally declared.

Anyone have any ideas for a simple way to set this variable outside the ajax call from the JSON response?

Comment: Well, when I had to do it, I declared global variables at window object.

Comment: Can you post more code, like where you are declaring the globalTotal variable, and how your ajax calls look.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. You use the IndexValue option ie.   $.ajax({
                                    url: globalURL, indexValue,
                                    headers: {
                                      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                                    },
                                    success: function(response) {}})